# error "permission denied" in VPS servers

Tags: permissions, vps

I am noob and I have two VPS servers. In the first server, I have user "bob". And I copied-pasted folder (home/bob) this user in the same folder in second VPS server. And when I tried to change a file in this folder (in the second server) a console speaks "permission denied ". What is the problem?

Comment: You should first change the owner of that copied folder in VPS B then you should be able to access those files

Comment: Hello and welcome to Ask Ubuntu! You appear to be a new user, so please take a look at our [tour] for advice on how to best use Ask Ubuntu to get help! Also, please take a look at our [ask] guide for some advice on writing awesome questions.

Answer (score 0):

Copying files tends to copy permissions, which includes the UID. You will need to reset the UID:

```
sudo chown -R youruser:youruser /path/to/folder
```

So, if you want to make `/home/bob` owned by `bob` on your second VPS, run:

```
sudo chown -R bob:bob /home/bob
```

I would recommend you read these two excellent pages from the Arch Wiki:

- [Users and Groups](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/users_and_groups)
- [File Permissions and Attributes](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/File_permissions_and_attributes)